Some ad requests on your inventory from the EEA, the UK, or Switzerland are missing a TC string, admob error
I've implemented CMP "a certified consent management platform (CMP)".according to admob request,  I followed google implementation here: But I am still getting error from admob console "Some ad requests on your inventory from the EEA, the UK, or Switzerland are missing a TC string"
Main activity code as below:
        googleMobileAdsConsentManager =
            GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    googleMobileAdsConsentManager.gatherConsent(
            this,
            consentError -> {
                if (consentError != null) {
                    // Consent not obtained in current session.
                   
                }
               

                if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                    initializeMobileAdsSdk();
                }

                if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.isPrivacyOptionsRequired()) {
                    // Regenerate the options menu to include a privacy setting.
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            });

    // This sample attempts to load ads using consent obtained in the previous session.
    if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
        initializeMobileAdsSdk();
    }

Anny suggestion?

After user grants or declines the Ads Personalisation request a key is stored in Shared preferences Automatically.
Shared preference Key name :- IABTCF_TCString
String tcString;
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
tcString = sp.getString("IABTCF_TCString", "Key not found");

Pass in AdMob
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(NativeAd.class, createAdMobExtras(tcString))  // Passing TC string
                .build();

private Bundle createAdMobExtras(String tcString) {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("tcString", tcString);  // Pass the TC string using the correct key
    return extras;
}


does this work even if no mediation?

Isabove solution valid for banner and native ads?

yes its valid for all kinds of Ads
